# Get Save Photo + Instagram option in UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: xcode, instagram, uidocumentinteraction

I ran into a problem which I can not seem to solve. I have a photo editing app and I want the user to be able to share the image on Instagram as well as, save it to the camera roll.

**My problem is:** For Instagram sharing I have to save the image with an .`ig` extension, however this way I don't get the "save photo"or any other option in the document controller. If I save the image with a `.png`extension, I don't get Instagram as an option. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Thanks!